# Why won't DraftSight run on Fedora 26 with Intel graphics?

Tags: fedora, solidworks, fedora-25, fedora-29

DraftSight 2017SP1 Linux (beta) worked on Fedora 24. It fails after upgrading to Fedora 26. Running it from the command line so you can see the low-level errors,

```
/opt/dassault-systemes/DraftSight/Linux/DraftSight 
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x238a050
Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x238a050
```

In the graphics environment you see the usual start screens, then error pop-ups which offer to report the error and then close the application when clicked. One says that error-reporting is not available.

Similarly with 2017SP3 and 2018SP0. Fedora updates are current as of today.

This system is an Intel core i3. lspci reports "Intel Corp Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen core processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)"

2018SP0 does work once an Nvidia GT710 card and the nvidia driver module are installed. It does not work with the nouveau driver module and the same card.

Does anybody have any insight as to the cause? A regression in Fedora, or a latent bug in DraftSight, or anything else?

Knowing whether it works with Fedora 26 and AMD graphics might be very helpful.

**Edit March 2018**

Doesn't work but differently on a system with AMD R5 230. No "Could not parse" errors, not anything else on the terminal window, but Draftsight starts up with the display all wrong and then locks up. Clicking the "X" gets to "the program is not responding".

Also worth noting that this isn't a Wayland issue. Systems are running Cinnamon and lightdm, so it's good old X.

Also a work-around, if performance is unimportant. (And it probably isn't, with Gen 4 Intel Graphics). Run it as a "remote" application on localhost, on a system with Intel graphics.

```
$ ssh -X 127.0.0.1
password: 
Last login: Wed Mar ...
-bash-4.4$ /opt/dassault-systemes/DraftSight/Linux/DraftSight 
(success)
```

**Further update Fedora 29, DraftSight 2018SP3**

New wrinkles for Nvidia, Cinnamon as above

Needs invocation

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6 /opt/dassault-systemes/DraftSight/Linux/DraftSight
```

otherwise fails with `/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 lookup error FT_DOne_MM_Var`

Also kernel 4.20 plus NVidia 390.87 fails to build. There's a patched NVidia installer that does work at if_not_false_then_true site.

Also does not install a `.desktop` file into /usr/share/applications

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems when I updated Fedora 24 to 25. The parse stylesheet messages still show up but I can run draftsight from an Xorg session, (not Wayland), using the nouveau drivers but only under root privileges using sudo .
You might try the following script:

sudo DISPLAY=$DISPLAY vblank_mode=1 /opt/dassault-systemes/DraftSight/Linux/DraftSight

Answer (score 0):

I can only get DraftSight to run as root under Fedora 27,  4.18.16-100.fc27.x86_64.  I have installed a VM with Ubuntu, and it runs fine, without elevated privileges.

Comment: I have draftsight-2018.2.0.3102-1.x86_64 working OK here on Fedora 27 non-root user (and tested 28, 29beta) given only an NVidia graphics card. We use Cinnamon not Gnome desktop environment, just in case that matters. Linux 4.16.13-200.fc27.x86_64 so possibly the latest kernel or other updates broke it?

Comment: Might also depend on the NVidia release ... here 390.67 on GT710.

Comment: @nigel222 Why would the graphics card affect it running.  I use XFCE, got tired of Gnome-Shell (miss the old days of Compiz-Fusion).  I tried installing Gnome3 (gnome-shell) and other Desktop Environments, and had the same issue.  I have a permission issue I am sure.  I do install fedora from the Server Package, and build it up from there, as opposed to installing a Workstation variant.

Comment: I don't know why but it does, as per my original question. Works on Fedora+Cinnamon using NVidia card and NVidia proprietary driver. Crashes using Nouveau driver, or with Intel on-CPU graphics.